# Make a slide animation in jquery for a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello i am trying to make a slider for a website i am making. I already made a "switcher" to change content, but without any animation. I would like it to look like the slider on [this website](http://sifjakobs.com). The work i already have done is on [this website](http://cornelia-whitt.myshopify.com).

The variable "content" in the JS is from a meta tag in the HTML (not in this one). In this example it is set to five.

My HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="slider">
    <div id="slider-object" class="slider-1 active">
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Hejsa 1</h3>
            <a href="#">Shop</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="pic">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="slider-object" class="slider-2">
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Hejsa 2</h3>
            <a href="#">Shop</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="pic">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="slider-object" class="slider-3">
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Hejsa 3</h3>
            <a href="#">Shop</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="pic">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="slider-object" class="slider-4">
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Hejsa 4</h3>
            <a href="#">Shop</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="pic">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="slider-object" class="slider-5">
        <div class="content">
            <h3>Hejsa 5</h3>
            <a href="#">Shop</a>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-img">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="pic">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="next" type="button">Next</button>
    <button class="previous" type="button">Previous</button>
</div>
```

My JS code looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var element = document.querySelector('meta[property="slider-count"]');
    var content = element && element.getAttribute("data");

    for (var i = 1; i <= content; i++)  {
        if ($(".slider-"+i).hasClass("active") === false) {
            $(".slider-"+i).hide();
        } else {
            var currentSlide = i;
        }
    }

    $(".next").click(function() {
        $(".slider-"+currentSlide).hide();
        var nextSlide = currentSlide+1;
        if (nextSlide > content) {
            currentSlide = 1;
        } else {
            currentSlide = nextSlide;
        }

        $(".slider-"+currentSlide).show();
    });
    $(".previous").click(function() {
        $(".slider-"+currentSlide).hide();
        var nextSlide = currentSlide-1;
        if (nextSlide < 1) {
            currentSlide = content;
        } else {
            currentSlide = nextSlide;
        }

        $(".slider-"+currentSlide).show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the website you mentioned as a good example uses a completely different approach: Instead of showing and hiding the panels, it just "moves them out of view". I tested around a bit and could reproduce the same behavior:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e48jpreg/)

I changed, well, pretty much everything:

- I removed the whole `.show()` and `.hide()` behavior.
- I added some CSS to display all the panels on one row but hide everything but one slide-object:

.

```
.slider {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.slider-object {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

- I added the animated additions and subtractions of the `margin-left`-value of the first `.slider-object`

.

```
$('.slider .slider-object:first-of-type').animate({
  marginLeft: (currentSlide - 1) * (step * -1) + 'px'
});
```

- I added some more variables to make the code more readable and removed the need for the meta-tag by counting the `.slider-object` with `$('.slider-object').length;`
- I changed `#slider-object` to `.slider-object` as you should not use IDs for objects that appear multiple times in a document
- I renamed `content` to `totalSlides`.
- And I did some other stuff, just have a look at the fiddle.

The website you mentioned as a good example uses a different method to do all this, with `transform: translate3d();` **which is better** and cleaner but more complex and I see this only right now when I finish this text. So, everybody is welcome to reproduce it with `transform: translate3d();` :)